# Forms & reports keep disappearing in open office base

Tags: mysql, forms, openoffice-base

### Heads up

I am very new to open office base so I suspect I am just missing some ui nuance.

### Setup

I have a mysql connection to a simple database. I update the structure in sequalpro then create forms and reports in open office base to same myself all the php code.

### Problem

I found that after working with base a little bit that some of my forms suddenly disappeared. The first time it happened I assumed I had forgotten to save or something like that. But after creating another form all the forms suddenly came back. I don't know what triggers the forms disappearing/reappearing but I really need this to be consistent.

### Versions

Using open office 4.1.2 on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

### Question

Why are my forms disappearing and reappearing?

Comment: The xml inside the Base file might be corrupted.  Has this disappear/reappear happened more than once?

Comment: You're probably right. I deleted the whole thing and started from scratch and havn't had the problem since. And yes it happened several times.